# Resize and replace all files in Laravel request based on size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I'm currently writing a middleware to detect when a file is being uploaded to manipulate it. The aim is to detect any/all images on the application that have a height or width that is larger than 500px, and if it does then resize it before allowing the request to continue.

At the moment I have this middleware with this image loop

```
class CheckImageSizes
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //Get each of the files that are being uploaded in the request, if there are no files this will just be ignored.
        foreach (array_flatten($request->files->all()) as $file) {
            $image = Image::make($file);
            if($image->height() > 500 || $image->width() > 500){
                $image->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
                //Replace the image inside the request with the new $image here
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Inside my `if` statement, how would i replace the image in the request and then return it so that when my controller processes the image, it handles the newly resized image?

Comment: 1- you can use this package to resize image: [link](http://image.intervention.io/)   2- the new image will be stored in the database?

Comment: I am using the package to resize the image already, but i'm not sure how to replace the `$request->file` with my newly generated one?

Comment: The image is already being stored, I just need to use my middleware to resize the image if its too big then place it back in the request so my original controller can continue to process the image as normal

Answer (score 1):

you can add the image to the request like this:

```
$request->merge([
    'image' => $image
]);
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge

Checking if input is a file:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $item) {
    if ($item instanceof UploadedFile) {
        $image = Image::make($item);
        if($image->height() > 500 || $image->width() > 500){
            $image->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $request->merge([$key => $image]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if my image is not called `image`, is there any way of getting the input name from my `$file` inside my `foreach` loop? The image input name will not always be the same so I would need to get the input name to use this method? So that maybe I can write `$request->merge([$file->inputname => $image]);` or something like that?

Comment: You could loop through all inputs and check if it is a image.


        `foreach ($request->all() as $item) {
            if ($item instanceof UploadedFile) {
                // do image manipulation
            }
        }`

Comment: This code looks great, although how would i do `$request->merge` to replace an array? For example, `$request->room_photos` is an array, so how would i build and replace the whole array?

Comment: You could check if `$item` is an array, then loop through and check if those entries are files. If yes do your image manipulation, rebuild the array with the new images and add it back into the request with `$request->merge()`.

Comment: For some reason `$request->merge()` doesn't seem to work with an array. Even trying `$request->replace()` to completely replace the array with a newly made image array doesn't work.